# why i getting four answer in one requset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojILH.png)[enter image description here][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojILH.png)[2]

I will appreciate it in advance if somebody could explain to me why I'm getting four answers at once and the setState undefined? I have been struggling with this bug.
Here you can check out my Repo.
https://github.com/AlejandroBryan/full-stack-mern/blob/master/blog/src/components/ShowBlogs.js

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code related to your problem, without it there is no way for us to help

Comment: thank you @PatrickEvans, here you got my github https://github.com/AlejandroBryan/full-stack-mern/blob/master/blog/src/components/ShowBlogs.js

Answer (score 0):

When you are attempting to write the blog data (https://github.com/AlejandroBryan/full-stack-mern/blob/master/blog/src/components/ShowBlogs.js#L61) you are assuming the `blog` is an array and that it, therefore, has a `map()` method.  The `blog` is being assigned like:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:3031/blogs/${params.id}`)
.then(response => this.setState({blog: response}))
.catch(err => console.error(err.message))
```

I suspect that your backend is returning an individual `blog` object rather than an array of `blog` objects.  You can check see what it is actually returning by writing to the log.  Right after [line 59](https://github.com/AlejandroBryan/full-stack-mern/blob/master/blog/src/components/ShowBlogs.js#L59), add

```
console.log(typeof(blog))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I analyzed your answer and I was able to solve the problem.